# Is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declare final

Tags: android

The following code at my adapter,i can't use "audioRightHolder.image.setImageBitmap(mIconPlay);" to update my imageView, how can i do that? thx a lot~
[The following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuodH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not really clear question. But may be you just need to write

```
view.setImageBitmap(mIconPlay);
```

instead of

```
audioRightHolder.image.setImageBitmap(mIconPlay);
```

Comment: Thx~, and sorry, i have a code update , it's wrong line brfore.

Comment: Did you add the comment "in this line..."? In your case you do not need to use audioRightHolder.image in onTouchListener. You just need to execute method of view, as i wrote in the answer.

Comment: yes, i try it, but it's not work for me，I update a new image, you can see "audioRightHolder.image.setImageBitmap(mIconPlay);" can access outside "case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:", but can't access in ACTION_UP.

Comment: Ok. If you really need to use audioRightHolder in onTouch event, try this: 1) in block if (view == null) add line audioRightHolder.image.setTag(audioRightHolder)
2) in onTouch event get audioRightHolder from tag of view and use it.

Answer (score 0):

you should define audioRightHolder as global variable

```
private AudioRightHolder audioRightHolder ;
```

or define as final variable in getView()

```
final AudioRightHolder audioRightHolder ;
```

because in anonymous inner class,you can only use local variable or global variable

Comment: Hi，i upload a new image, ican't define "audioRightHolder" as final，cos it's will error in "audioRightHolder = new AudioRightHolder();" and "audioRightHolder = (AudioRightHolder) tempView.getTag();".